# Is it possible to do SLAM with few IR sensors like Buddy?

Tags: mobile-robot, localization, slam, mapping, rangefinder

I saw [Buddy](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/buddy-your-family-s-companion-robot/x/11637197#/story)'s page and want to purchase for my SLAM research. However, I wonder is it possible to program Buddy for SLAM?

According to Buddy's spec, they're only few IR's, sonars and a camera. As I know, most SLAM algorithms are implemented with powerful sensors such as RGBD/stereo camera, or even laser range finder.

Are there any pepers mention about IR-based SLAM?

Comment: long story short Yes. Actually, you can build SLAM with only one sensor. More sensors more accuracy.

Comment: @CroCo's comment deserves to be an answer.  Very well put.

Answer (score 2):

I did casually search for something like this a year or two ago. "Sparse sensing" or "sensing limited" were the sort of phrases that cropped up.

[Kris Beevers](http://cs.krisbeevers.com/) has some interesting publications in this sort of area, such as [SLAM With Sparse Sensing](http://cs.krisbeevers.com/research/slam_icra06.pdf). His general approach was to maintain previous sensor readings while changing the direction of the robot, to build up a "scan" comprising several sets of readings. This approach might be sensitive to encoder errors or any other movement inaccuracies during the scan, but still worth investigating.

Answer (score 1):

SLAM can be done Using many different way, in this case,
Yes Buddy can map around him using its sensors : 
RGB camera, IR sensor, Ultra sound Sensor, Encoder.
The result depend of the algorithme you are using.

We are also working on a 3D camera to allow buddy to have a better input of the world.